# Call method that sorts the integers of array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I would like to make the code below work, but I do not know how exactly to make run the empty method. There has to be a logic that sorts the array of integers, but I do not understand how to make it work.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/U1pQ9B

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void SortAscending(int[] a, out int []b)
    {
        // Write your code here 
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Array Size :");       // 1 - Enter the array Length
        int ArraySize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());     // 2 - Put the Number for array Length in variable int ArraySize 
        int[] Arr = new int[ArraySize];                    // 3 - put the number of the input as a default Length value
        int[] Arr_Ascending;                               // 4 - initialize an array Arr_Ascending
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Input Array Elements :"); // 5  - 

        for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Element number " + (i + 1)+" :");
            Arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        SortAscending( Arr,out Arr_Ascending);
        Console.Write("Ascending :");

        for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(Arr_Ascending[i] + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your task to implement a sorting algorithm from scratch? If so, you may want to look up a simple one, such as bubble sort, and implement that. If you just want an off-the-shelf implementation, you could use `Array.Sort`.

Comment: `//Wtrie your code here ` after you do that, get back to us with a proper question.  And also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LINQ`:

Replace the line

```
SortAscending( Arr,out Arr_Ascending);
```

By

```
Arr_Ascending = Arr.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Don't forget to reference the package `System.Linq`

Updated fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PNKp70

Comment: Thank you a lot you are amazing! thank you, it looks like Linq is a bit deal!